# Finding Sum and Average of Floating-Point Numbers from File (python 3.5)

Tags: floating-point, sum, average, python-3.5

I am writing a program that allows a user to open a file and parse the text for spam confidence. I have been able to create this loop but I now need to create a sum of all these numbers so I can find the average. I am having trouble using other solutions I have seen since the numbers are not integers. Some examples of the floating-point numbers are: Spam: 0.7605, 0.6932, 0.7558, 0.6526. The program needs to be able to read two different files so I cannot create a list.

Here is what I have right now:

```
sum = 0
average=0
total=0

fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
fhand = open(fname)
count=0
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence: ") :
        spam = line[19:].strip()
        spam = float (spam)
        print('Spam:', spam)
        count = count + 1

sum(float(item) for item in spam)

average= total/ count
print('Average: ', average)
```

It is breaking at
    sum(float(item) for item in spam)

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are treating `spam` like a list in the sum function.

You can append to the spam list like so:

```
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence: ") :
        temp = line[19:].strip()
        spam.append(float (temp))
        print('Spam:', spam)
        # count is not needed if spam is a list count = len(spam)
        count = count + 1

sum(float(item) for item in spam)
```

or Better yet just sum it up when iterating the first time :

```
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence: ") :
        spam = line[19:].strip()
        sum += float (spam)
```